# [B cannot be cast to javax.swing.ImageIcon

Tags: java

what can my code problem ,, this is my code in the table, every time I click an error appears

I would like the picture on the table to be displayed on the label, how do you think?
dimg. is my jlabel
thank you

```
    private void prodtableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)prodtable.getModel();

    int Myindex = prodtable.getSelectedRow();
    prodcode.setText(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 0).toString());
    prodname.setText(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 1).toString());
    prodqty.setText(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 2).toString());
    prodprice.setText(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 3).toString());

   ImageIcon image1= (ImageIcon)prodtable.getValueAt(Myindex,4);
   Image image2 = 
     image1.getImage().getScaledInstance(dimg.getWidth(),dimg.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
   ImageIcon image3 =new ImageIcon (image2);
   dimg.setIcon(image3);
```

this is the error that appears:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to 
  javax.swing.ImageIcon
  at admin.prodtableMouseClicked(admin.java:411)
  at admin.access$200(admin.java:32)
  at admin$3.mouseClicked(admin.java:150)
  at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
  at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
  at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
  at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
```

Comment: `[B` probably represents a byte array. which line is `at admin.prodtableMouseClicked(admin.java:411)`?

Comment: You need to debug this thing, first of all by checking what is held in your table model here: `prodtable.getValueAt(Myindex,4);`

Comment: I already figured as much (see my second comment). You're casting a byte array to ImageIcon (as the error is telling you) on that line, and that simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`prodtable.getValueAt(Myindex,4);` is returning a byte array.

The cast operator **does not** convert anything<sup>1</sup>. It's merely a type assertion: You're saying that whatever `getValueAt` returns, it *IS* an ImageIcon. It isn't, so this fails.

Perhaps that byte array is the content of a jpeg or PNG image or whatnot, in which case you'd have to throw it through e.g. Toolkit's methods to turn those into Image objects. Your code pastes don't give any insights on what it might be.

[1] When the thing in the parens is a primitive type, it -does- convert. Point is, `ImageIcon` isn't a primitive.